# Is it possible to create a rule in a different account?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

Using CDK I am trying to create an event bus rule in a different account:

```
// Getting source bus ARN
const sourceBusArn = Stack.of(this).formatArn({
  region: this.region,
  service: 'events',
  account: Config.sourceAccount,
  resource: 'event-bus',
  resourceName: Config.sourceBusName,
});

// Retrieving source bus
const sourceBus = EventBus.fromEventBusArn(this, 'SourceBus', sourceBusArn);

// creating rule to forward source bus events to target buses
new Rule(this, 'CrossAccountSourceRule', {
  eventPattern: Config.eventPattern,
  eventBus: sourceBus,
  targets: [new EventBusTarget(targetBus)],
});
```

Here `Config.sourceAccount` is an external account, different from the one CDK is being executed in. The `Config.sourceBusName` bus exists in that account, and has policy allowing to create rules from external accounts in the same organization.

But attempt to create the rule throws exception `Event bus <bus-in-external-account> does not exist. Status Code: 400`. Is it possible to create a rule in a different account like this or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. When importing bus from the source account instead of `EventBus.fromEventBusArn` use `EventBus.fromEventBusAttributes` - but with one twist: pass source bus ARN as both bus name and bus ARN:

```
// Getting source bus ARN
const sourceBusArn = Stack.of(this).formatArn({
  region: this.region,
  service: 'events',
  account: Config.sourceAccount,
  resource: 'event-bus',
  resourceName: Config.sourceBusName,
});

// Retrieving source bus. Pass ARN both as name and Arn props.
const sourceCoreBus = EventBus.fromEventBusAttributes(this, 'SourceCoreBus', {
  eventBusName: sourceBusArn,
  eventBusArn: sourceBusArn,
  eventBusPolicy: '',
});

// creating rule to forward source bus events to target buses
new Rule(this, 'CrossAccountSourceRule', {
  eventPattern: Config.eventPattern,
  eventBus: sourceBus,
  targets: [new EventBusTarget(targetBus)],
});
```

This will create rule in the external account. Don't forget that the bus you're trying to access has to have required permission policy in place, e.g.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"<id-of-account-that-creates-rules>"
         },
         "Action":[
            "events:DescribeEventBus",
            "events:PutRule",
            "events:PutTargets",
            "events:DeleteRule",
            "events:RemoveTargets",
            "events:DisableRule",
            "events:EnableRule",
            "events:TagResource",
            "events:UntagResource",
            "events:DescribeRule",
            "events:ListTargetsByRule",
            "events:ListTagsForResource"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:<id-of-source-account>:event-bus/<bus-name>",
            "arn:aws:events:us-west-2:<id-of-source-account>:rule/<bus-name>/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**UPDATE:** A bit of explanation. The above solution works because under the hood Rule construct uses Level 1 [CfnRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.CfnRule.html) construct. And one of its props `EventBusName` can be either [bus name or ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.CfnRule.html#construct-props). So when ARN is passed instead of name - it is used as such. And generated CloudFormation template looks like this (relevant fragment):

```
  "CrossAccountSourceRuleAF67328": {
   "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
   "Properties": {
    "EventBusName": {
     "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
       "arn:",
       {
        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
       },
       ":events:",
       {
        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
       },
       ":1234567890:event-bus/bus-name"
      ]
     ]
    },
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that it works. Can you share the bit of the resulting CloudFormation template that creates the rule?

Comment: @gshpychka I added a bit of explanation plus fragment of the template.

Comment: Okay, I was certain that a CloudFormation stack cannot just deploy a resource in a different environment like that. Can you confirm that this deploys fine and actually creates the rule in another account?

Comment: I thought so too, that CloudFormation stack is bound to specific environment - account and region, but apparently it's not always the case, at least for some resources. Yes, when the proper permission policy was set on another account's bus - it worked. The rule was created successfully and the rule works (it uses event bus in the original account as a target).

Comment: But where is the rule created? Is it actually in the source account, or is it in the current account, as I would expect?

Comment: It's created in the source account, the one ARN is pointing to, different from the one stack is deployed to.

Comment: Seems it still doesn't work if the bus is in a different region.